# Commit transaction without begin transaction

Tags: sql-server

I accidentally ran into a situation that I didn't put `Begin Transaction` at the beginning of my stored procedure and just wrote `Commit Transaction` as you can see below

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE dbo.spTest
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @MyId INT=1

BEGIN TRY 
UPDATE Test
SET
    -- Id -- this column value is auto-generated
    CharName = 'david'
WHERE id=4

--Just to test locking behavior 
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
    SET @MyId=2;
END


COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END CATCH 

END
```

I expected SQL Server to give me a run time error but it didn't happen. Of course I should mention that based on my test it didn't acquire any lock on the table due to the lack of `Begin Transaction` but what is the point of `COMMIT TRANSACTION` and `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` in such a condition and why didn't SQL Server raise any error?

Edit:
if i remove while block and put `WaitFor` Sql raise error when reaches to     `COMMIT TRANSACTION`

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE dbo.spTest
AS
BEGIN


    UPDATE Test
    SET  CharName = 'david'
    WHERE id=4

      PRINT 'waiting for a minute '
      WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';


  COMMIT TRANSACTION 

END
```

Now i am receiving this error

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

Comment: The locks on tables (or more precisely: on **rows**) are **independent** of whether or not you've defined / started an explicit transaction. If you haven't, then each statement is run inside its own **implicit** transaction, and lock **are applied**

Comment: It's pointless - if there's no `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then there is no explicit transaction in place - calling `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` in such a case is equivalent to a "no operation" - it doesn't do anything, it has no benefit whatsoever ....

Comment: but if i don't define explicit transaction when it is inside while block table's change has  committed and no lock is on the row

Comment: Setting a **variable** doesn't have anything to do with a table/row lock anyways..... that would work **even IF** the row being updated above was still locked..... this whole snippet of code seems rather suspicious and doesn't seem to serve any real purpose - other to confuse later readers....

Comment: if its pointless why sql server didn't raise any error,because it is not linked to any transaction

Comment: this stored procedure is just for testing lock and transaction in sql server and there is not any other point.

Comment: purpose of while block is when the session falls into an infinite loop and in another session you select from this table and see if there is any lock on the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > what is the point of COMMIT TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK TRANSACTION in such a condition?

There is no point in this case

> > and why didn't SQL Server raise any error?

I don't see any code that would raise an error. It would help if you could explain where and why you think an error should be raised

With regards to whatever you're actually doing here;

If the purpose of this proc is to hold a transaction open, you'd need something more like this:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE dbo.spTest
AS
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE Test
    SET  CharName = 'david'
    WHERE id=4

    --Endless loop
    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN
      PRINT 'waiting for a minute inside a transaction. Try something from another session'
      WAITFOR DELAY '00:01';
    END

  -- Transaction will actually never be committed 
  -- Because this line will never be reached
  -- because it's preceded by an endless loop
  COMMIT TRANSACTION 

END
```

The `TRY / CATCH` is a bit of a distraction. I've removed it.

Comment: thanks @Nick,i think in this situation we can remove while block and just put WAITFOR DELAY